# Zend Framework - How can i share common code between some of a controller's actions?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-controller

To keep my controllers as DRY as possible i need to share some common code (a big chunk of code) between say 2 of my controller's actions and not all of them and i need access variables in this shared code in my actions.

For example:

```
class FirstController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

   public function firstAction() {
     //common code here: contains an array $columns 
   } 
   public function secondAction() { 
       //common code here: contains an array $columns also 

   } 

   //other actions
}
```

so how can I refactor this to put the common code in one place and be able to access `$columns` and in `firstAction()` and `secondAction()`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't recommend you to use a **base controller**. It's overkilling and heavy for such a small task. Since you want to share common code within one controller, use instead an action helper and a class attribute `$columns` that you can send as argument to your action helper.

Read more about [action helpers](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html) here.

> Action Helpers allow developers to inject runtime and/or on-demand
>   functionality into any Action Controllers that extend
>   Zend_Controller_Action. Action Helpers aim to minimize the necessity
>   to extend the abstract Action Controller in order to inject common
>   Action Controller functionality.

Comment: Referenced URL is incorrect try - https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html

Answer (score 1):

You can create new class and extend `Zend_Controller_Action` then extend your newly created class not `Zend_Controller_Action`

**example:**

```
class CommonactionsController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

   public function firstAction() {
     //common code here : contains an array $columns 
   } 
   public function secondAction() { 
       //common code here : contains an array $columns also 

   } 

   //other actions
}
```

and then:

```
class FirstController extends CommonactionsController {
    // here you can use all your common actions...
}
```

second controller..

```
class SecondController extends CommonactionsController {
    // here you can use all your common actions...
}
```

and so on...

Comment: I would recommand this method for new behaviors that must be implemented in every controllers, like making the controllers aware of a dependency injection container, otherwise I would rely on either action helpers or controller plugins

Comment: I would recommend @Liyali's solution over this one. I'm not saying this is bad, but the other is better. Just my opinion :). The reason being he mentions a big chunk of code which will need to be loaded for every controller, although it is needed in only two. An action helper is loaded only when needed.